# Sending to a signer with 2 email addresses: use a signing group?

Tags: docusignapi

Using API code, we currently send a customized per person envelope/document to thousands of recipients using our email account set up for them.  Some of the recipients don't use the standard email account set up for them.  We have on file their personal email account as well.

We need to send the document to both email accounts (for the same person) in hopes that they will see one of them and sign the document.

After much research in Docusign support and on Stackoverflow, I could not find an 'alternate' email address tag in Docusign.  I did find signing group, which may work if the recipient name can be the same for different email addresses, and I can create the signing group on the fly when I am creating the envelope.

Is this a wise way to go to get the doc to the recipient at multiple addresses, or did I miss something?  Any pitfalls in implementing this method as stated, or any other advice?

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signing groups are attached to the account, not the envelope. Also, there is a limit of 50 signing groups, so this is not the way to go to send one envelope to the same person at multiple email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create two recipient entries for the same person, one recipient per email address. If the same `routingOrder` is used then the invitation to sign will be sent to both email addresses.

Since only one of the recipients will actually work, you'd then need to delete the other recipient after the "real one" completes. Use Connect or eventNotification instead of polling to detect when one of the recipients completes (signs).

You could also keep track of which email address works for a given person so you don't have to repeat the next time you want them to sign something.

Comment: I will have to look into deleting one recipient after the other signs.  A DocuSign API person sent me code on signing groups where I can delete the signing group after I apply it to the envelope.  I'm still waiting on clarification that deleting the signing group won't affect re-sending the envelope if they don't respond.

Comment: UPDATE: I have successfully tested using API the process of creating a signing group, assigning it to an envelope as signer, posting the envelope, and then delete the signing group.  Both emails in the signing group received the letter.  When one signed it, the other is shown a completed document.  I also tested resending (through the UI), it is sent to both emails.